# How to retrieve the owner or Drive ID of a document with Google APIs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Working with Google APIs (Sheet, v4) in JavaScript, I need to verify the origin of a sheet, either by using an owner ID or the Drive ID where it is hosted (regardless of the folder).

I looked at the properties of the Spreadsheet as well as the documentation but couldn't find this essential information. Thank you. Thank you.

Here is the documentation consulted:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "1kbxkHPzlHy35v9hNSE8pxJljF_MsTBqXER2xIFzm0W0",
  "properties": {
    "title": "Goco",
    "locale": "fr_FR",
    "autoRecalc": "ON_CHANGE",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
  }
}
```

No property contains any information about the owner or the Drive.

Comment: Your answer is contained in your question, perhaps unbeknownst to you. The user of a document is accessed through the drive api, not sheet api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Drive API to get the email address of a file give the ID.

```
function getOwner() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  Logger.log(file.getOwner().getEmail());
}
```